# How to group by a set of numbers in a column

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table as below. I want to do a group by in such a way that 1-4 weeknums are joined together and 5-8 weeknums are joined together. Or in other words i want to get the monthly total from below fields

```
table1

weeknum    amount     
1          1000     
2          1100     
3          1200     
4          1300     
5          1400     
6          1500     
7          1600     
8          1700
```

The output i need is as below

```
output
max(weeknum)       sum(amount)
4                   4600
8                   6200
```

The below answer did not work exactly for my actual values as below. I want to start with 4 weeks grouping. The formula (weeknum-1)/4 returns 3 groups as in the expected is only 2

```
weeknum Group Expr    Expected Group Expr 
1855   463           463     
1856   463           463
1857   464           463
1858   464           463
1859   464           464 
1860   464           464
1861   465           464 
1862   465           464
```

Need to execute the query in oracle

Answer (score 2):

Try using [`FLOOR`](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/floor.php) that rounds the number down in the `group by` clause:

```
SELECT MAX(t.weeknum),sum(amount)
FROM table1 t
GROUP BY FLOOR((t.weeknum-1)/4)
```

This will make sure every 4 weeks are treated as a group :

```
(1-1)/4 -> 0
(2-1)/4 -> 0
...
(5-1)/4 -> 1
```